# A question about class member function that returns a structure

Tags: c++, function, class

I had a trouble when I read C++ Primer Plus.

```
class AcctABC
{
private:
    string fullName;
    long acctNum;
    double balance;
protected:
    struct Formatting
    {
         std::ios_base::fmtflags flag;
         std::streamsize pr;
    };
    const std::string & FullName() const {return fullName;}
    long AcctNum() const {return acctNum;}
    Formatting SetFormat() const;
    void Restore(Formatting & f) const;
public: 
    AcctABC(const std::string & s = "Nullbody", long an = -1,
                double bal = 0.0);
    void Deposit(double amt) ;
    virtual void Withdraw(double amt) = 0;
    double Balance() const {return balance;};
    virtual void ViewAcct() const = 0;
    virtual ~AcctABC() {}
};
```

and here are two definitions of class member funcions in the protected scope.

```
AcctABC::Formatting AcctABC::SetFormat() const
{
    Formatting f;
    f.flag = 
        cout.setf(ios_base::fixed, ios_base::floatfield);
    f.pr = cout.precision(2);
    return f; 
}
void AcctABC::Restore(Formatting & f) const
{
    cout.setf(f.flag, ios_base::floatfield);
    cout.precision(f.pr);
}
```

we can see the return of the first class member function, there is a `AcctABC::`,but in the declaration there isn't, and the argument of the second class member function, we needn't use the `AcctABC::`, I want to know why the rule is like this.

Comment: There's a difference between asking what the rule is, and why the rule is what it is. Which are you interested in?

Comment: both! If I know why the rule is like this, I will remember what the rule is well. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is about qualified names. The fully qualified name of the return struct is `AcctABC::Formatting`. However the `AcctABC::` can be omitted if you are already in the scope of an `AcctABC` definition. That is why `AcctABC::` is not necessary in the `SetFormat` declaration, or in the body of the `SetFormat` definition, or the parameter list of the `Restore` definition.

However the return type of a method definition outside of a class definition is not considered to be in the scope of the class, so there a fully qualified name is required.

I'm not certain exactly why this rule is as it is. I guess it has something to do with the fact that to implement a rule where the return type was in scope would mean the compiler having to read ahead to find the method definition before applying that to the return type. In other words the rule just makes things a little easier for the compiler.